# How to move pointer to specific bytes and read using Pickle Library in Python?

Tags: python

everyone!

I need a little bit of help in working with Binary Files (.dat) in python.
I am using Pickle Library to input in file which succeeds but when it comes to reading from file, my program does not work.

I need help in;

1. calculating the file size of the specific file, in bytes.
2. moving the pointer to specific bytes in file. (using .seek would be better.)
3. reading a specific byte from file. (using pickle.load would be better.)
4. looping over the specific file to print all bytes. (I get EOFError using while True: )

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my testing code so far and it has a lot of issues.

```
import pickle

with open ("BinaryFile.dat" , mode = "ab") as MyFile:
    pickle.dump("New" , MyFile)
with open("BinaryFile.dat" , mode = "rb") as MyReadFile:
    MyReadFile.seek(3)
    NewLine = pickle.load(MyReadFile)
    print (NewLine)
 input("-> ")
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? If you just `dump` into a file opened as `wb` and then `load` from file opened as `rb`, without any `seek`, that would work.

Comment: This is just a testing code so I can understand how they are supposed to work. Real program is supposed to add, print, delete, search records that are saved in binary. I want to read specific records like for example, skipping the first 2 bytes then reading the byte after it.

Comment: That's not how pickle works. You cannot skip 2 bytes and then read the rest. It will fail. And that is what happened here. If you want so much control over reading and writing, that you are going to manipulate it byte-by-byte, then don't use `pickle` at all. Just do `f.write("blah blah blah")` and `blah = f.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pickle` will do everything for you, just check its [API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle

with open ('BinaryFile.dat', mode='ab') as MyFile:
    pickle.dump('New', MyFile)
    pickle.dump([1, 2], MyFile)
    pickle.dump(pickle.dump, MyFile)
    # etc.

with open('BinaryFile.dat', mode='rb') as MyReadFile:
    try:
        while 1:
            print pickle.load(MyReadFile)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is 'pass' supposed to do and how to print only one record using pickle? Like let's suppose there are 7 records in one line in a binary file and each record consists of 2 bytes, and I want to read the 3 record. So, how can I skip the first 2 records (4 bytes) and print the 2 bytes after it and leave the rest.

Comment: as far as I understand, they are pickled in "one-object-per-read" way, so just make N calls (by using `pickle.load`) to get first N objects. `pass` does nothing, it's a way to catch the "end of file" exception.

Comment: How can I assign fix number of bytes to a variable which contents are to be stored in the binary file. e.g: UserName is to be of 20 bytes and the input takes up only 8 bytes, so how can I calculate the remaining bytes and add it to the variable as empty bytes?

Comment: if you need such a full control over the file structure, then I suggest to switch to `pickle.dumps` & `pickle.loads`, that just returns bytes. later you can count the payload size: `payload = pickle.dumps(something); length=len(payload)` and add empty bytes if needed: `payload.ljust(20, '\x00')`. but in this case you have to add some byte-delimiter to you file to basically split pickled objects later